# Ошибки вида "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified" в CRON

Tags: ubuntu, администрирование, cron

В кроне стоит такая команда (автоочистка кэша):

```
sudo find /tmp/ -name "magick-*" -type f -delete
```

(выполняется ежесуточно)

В итоге мне каждые сутки на почту приходит это:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Сама команда, разумеется не выполняется

Нашел примерное решение ([отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error)):

> Granting the user to use that command without prompting for password
> should resolve the problem.
>
> First open a shell console and type:
>
> `sudo visudo`
>
> Then edit that file to add to the very end:
>
> `username ALL = NOPASSWD: /fullpath/to/command, /fullpath/to/othercommand`
>
> eg
>
> `john ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff, /sbin/start, /sbin/stop`
>
> will allow user john to sudo poweroff, start and stop without being
> prompted for password.

Не понятны только 2 вещи: во-первых, какой полный путь к команде "find", во-вторых, как узнать от какого юзера выполняется крон.

Ну и другие варианты решения проблемы приветствуются

Comment: «как узнать от какого юзера выполняется» — в письме это написано. в поле "to: "

Comment: Александр спасибо! Теперь бы еще путь к команде find узнать...